VBA background process
I would like to create a code that works in the background.
In this case my code will check dates, calculations for total and Find cells. however, I don't want it to pause my Excel window. Instead, I want to be able to work while those things are happening.
Is that possible?
I want to do this:
If Not Intersect(Target, ReportTab.Range("L2:L900000")) Is Nothing And Selection.Count = 1 Then
            If ActiveCell.Value = "FIN - UPLOADED" Then
                On Error GoTo ErrorbackupCategory
                PoToFind = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Value
                INVToFind = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Value
                Do While worklogTab.Cells(wolc, 4).Value >= 0
                    If worklogTab.Cells(wolc, 4) = PoToFind And worklogTab.Cells(wolc, 3) = INVToFind Then
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, C#) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -11)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Customer_Name) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Document_Number) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, PO_Number) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, DateColumn) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Due_Date) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Current_Trx_Amount) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, PM_Owner) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, PM_Notes) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Finance_Comments) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, NotesColumn) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, CategoryCOlumn) = ActiveCell
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Uploaded_Date) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Owner) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Alert_Ticket_#) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Requestor) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)
                        Exit Do
                    ElseIf worklogTab.Cells(wolc, 4) = 0 Then
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, C#) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -11)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Customer_Name) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Document_Number) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, PO_Number) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, DateColumn) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Due_Date) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Current_Trx_Amount) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, PM_Owner) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, PM_Notes) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Finance_Comments) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, NotesColumn) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, CategoryCOlumn) = ActiveCell
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Uploaded_Date) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Owner) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Alert_Ticket_#) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
                        worklogTab.Cells(wolc, Requestor) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    wolc = wolc + 1
                Loop
            ElseIf Not ActiveCell.Value = "FIN - UPLOADED" Then
                PoToFind = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Value
                Do While worklogTab.Cells(wolc, 4) > 0
                    If worklogTab.Cells(wolc, 4) = PoToFind Then
                        worklogTab.Rows(wolc).Delete
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    wolc = wolc + 1
                Loop
Exit Sub
ErrorbackupCategory: MsgBox "Error ocurred at: " & "Backing-Up Uploads" & vbNewLine & "Error: " & ErrorBackingUp
Resume Next
            End If
    End If


Typically code like this can't run in the background.  If you want this because it takes to long to run, maybe ask about speeding it up...

When you add a DoEvents statement inside your loop, the user can continue to work. However, you need to be careful because this might change ActiveCell, so your code would break - I assume you could simple use Target instead of that (or you need to save ActiveCell into a Range variable and use that). That said: You can probably rework the code and speed it up, eg by reading the content of worklogTab into an Array variable to search for the correct row.

Is this code inside of a Change event?

I honestly don’t know hot to answer that question. This goes inside the Module of the sheet. Does that helps?

Why does it need to run in the background though?  Does it take too long?  How many rows of data do you have?  You're using ActiveCell, but it's not clear what that is - Target is the changed cell which triggers the code...

Would help if you could update your post to include the full code (everything from Sub... to End Sub, including all variable declarations)

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
